# How do I nest an existing key-value pair inside another object in Mongodb?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, object-oriented-database

I have a collection with multiple documents inside Mongodb. The document in this collection looks like -

```
{
    "name": "xyz",
    "address": "abc",
    "phone": "100"
}
```

I wish to move some key-value pairs into another object in the same document. So, the final document looks like -

```
{
    "name": "xyz",
    "details": {
        "address": "abc",
        "phone": 100
    }
}
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
    {},
    {
        $rename: {
            "address": "details.address",
            "phone": "details.phone"
        }
    })
```